# sending socket with socketIO in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io, native

Im trying to create mobile app in react native that controls raspberry pi with sockets. At first Im trying to send socket but Im getting lost. First I created simple interface, now Im trying to send socket to localhost:8888.

I have main file app.js just with navigator to screens:

```html
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

import ConnectScreen from './src/screens/ConnectScreen';
import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import InfoScreen from './src/screens/InfoScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Connect: ConnectScreen,
      Main: MainScreen,
      Info: InfoScreen,
    },{
      initialRouteName: 'Connect',
      defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false,
      }
    }
);


export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

and my first client screen is ConnectScreen, there are textinput for ip(im not using yet, I will just connect to localhost) and button where I call function connectWifi(). After  succesfull connection I want to go to MainScreen where I send socket with data every second.

I have multiple questions:

1. how to merge MainScreen structure with socket implementation
2. Im still getting error in MainScreen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ3X7.png)
3. what is the most simple way to recieve that socket just on temporary server

here is git with main app.js and screens https://github.com/Ersii/rccar

Comment: fixed error in MainScreen but now Im getting TypeError attempted to assign to readonly property in ConnectScreen any tips what am I doing wrong there? it doesnt say which line